# Rails Getting event trigger from remote:true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a link_to with remote:true on a button in one of my views in Rails.

I would like to change the properties of that button [lets just say turn it blue] after the AJAX is called and processes my .js.erb file that it is pointed towards, but I can't figure out how to get that object passed to my .js.erb. If I were not using remote:true, but using raw/home-made AJAX, what I would want is `this` or `$(this)`, but I can't figure out how to pass `this` to my `.js.erb` file

**Example code (simplified):**

*index.html*

```
link_to("Load This One", show_path(1), {:remote true})
```

*show.js.erb*

```
//Load some modal
$("#myModal .modalcontent).html("<%=.......>"); 
$("#myModal").modal();
// ****** change properties on button that loaded that modal
$( this).css('color', 'blue');
```

I want to know how can I get that link_to anchor in my show.js.erb. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

---

[**UJS Ajax Hooks**](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)

You *could* capture the event with standard UJS ajax in your app's `asset pipeline`:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:send", "a", function(xhr){
   $(this).css("color", "blue");
}).on("ajax:success", "a", function(data, status, xhr) {
   alert("Ajax Success!!");
});
```

---

**ID**

The only other way to effectively "bind" elements on the backend is by using the `id` attribute in your DOM:

```
#app/views/controller/your_view.html.erb
<%= link_to "Load", show_path(1), remote: true, id: "1" %>
```

As long as the `id` attribute corresponds with the object you pass through to the controller, you'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def show
      ...
      @id = params[:id]
      respond_to do |format|
         format.js #-> show.js.erb
      end
   end
end

#app/views/your_controller/show.js.erb
$('# <%=j @id %>').css('color', 'blue')
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your link_to

```
<%= link_to("Load This One", show_path(1), remote: true, id: 'my-button') %>
```

Then just use this link id to change its color

in your js.erb file

```
$('#my-button').css('color', 'blue')
```